# general expense vs capital expense

Tags: taxes, business

If the water main outside of my business has ruptured and I paid the entire $10,000 to have it repaired can I write that off as a general expense on the business or do I have to depreciate it?

Comment: Does your business own the water main? You should probably ask your accountant. If you own the asset then you might have to treat the repair as a capital expense. Also, please include country and state.

Comment: Hi Leah. Tax questions require you to mention the country, or else your question may be closed as unclear.